# Aurelia, au command not found after installing aurelia-cli

Tags: npm, aurelia

I have `node v4.6.1` installed on my system. When I tried installing `aurelia-cli` by executing `npm install aurelia-cli -g`, the installation went through. This is the output.

```
npm install -g aurelia-cli

/opt/node-v4.6.1-linux-x64/bin/aurelia -> /opt/node-v4.6.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/bin/aurelia-cli.js
/opt/node-v4.6.1-linux-x64/bin/au -> /opt/node-v4.6.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/bin/aurelia-cli.js
aurelia-cli@0.21.0 /opt/node-v4.6.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli
├── aurelia-polyfills@1.1.1 (aurelia-pal@1.0.0)
├── aurelia-dependency-injection@1.2.0 (aurelia-pal@1.0.0, aurelia-metadata@1.0.2)
└── npm@3.10.9
```

After this when I tried doing `au new` to start new aurelia project I got error saying `au command not found`.

PS: I am totally new to npm and node, so I am unsure if the installation went cleanly. I cant seem to find anything related to this anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16. I forgot the sudo:

```
sudo npm install aurelia-cli -g
```